# What's the correct word for referring to the "size" of a programme at the university?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

If I want to refer to the "size" of a programme at the university, what word should I use? By "size" I mean things such as the number of terms and courses that the programme spans.

I have considered the following options:

> The scope of the programme

> The extent of the programme

> The range of the programme

However, I haven't found any solid proof that any one of these is the right word for the meaning I'm after. So, my question, then, is whether any one of these works, or whether I should use a different word altogether (in that case, what word)?

As always, I'd be truly grateful for any help I could get here :)

Comment: Why wouldn’t you use “size” to describe the size of the program?

Comment: Or 'length' to refer to the number of terms?

Comment: @ColleenV Hm... because to my ears "size" sounds extremely odd... But you're saying that'd work?

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, that works in some cases, but not when I want to include other factors such as number of courses for instance...

Comment: @ColleenV "Size" is pretty ambiguous - it doesn't necessarily mean "the number and variety of courses."  It could refer to the number of students graduating per year or the number of faculty members or even the amount of physical office space occupied in the building.

Comment: @CanadianYankee I agree that’s a reason someone might have to not want to use it, but I was asking about Helen’s reason, which is apparently “it sounds weird”. We can help explain whether or not something is ambiguous, we can’t really fix something sounding weird to someone.

Comment: @ColleenV Haha, what I meant was that to my non-native ears it sounds weird; or, in other words: I simply thought you can't use "size" in this context. But you're saying I can, right? Which is excellent news in that case!

Comment: @CanadianYankee actually, that's not a drawback in this case, but rather a plus. I need a vague word that could include all of these things, so, if "size" is a word I can use here, then great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Length, breadth and depth of the program". This allows you to describe the structure in two dimensions.

A broad program covers many different topics.  A deep program covers only a few topics but covers those very completely. A long program lasts for many terms and so allows for greater breadth and/or depth.

However "scope" and "range" are useful terms.  You can talk about a program having a broad scope.

Comment: This is a truly useful answer (as always)! Thank you! I always thought "broad" and "deep" used in this way were translationese from my own language, so it's really good to know that it works in English too! Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

While a vaguer term might include everything you need it to and more, I think it is best to be precise, especially in formal writing. If your connotations are the number of terms and the numbers of courses, then one refers to time and the other to variety. You could therefore say:

> the ***length*** and ***diversity*** of the programme

*Diversity* is defined as

> the fact of many different types of things or people being included in something; a range of different things or people ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/diversity))

Comment: Diversity is becoming an increasingly important topic in many organizations, and is often used to refer to the people within the organization. Without additional context, one might assume the "diversity of the program" refers to the diversity of its *members* rather than its *content*, so watch out for unintended connotations.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie You are right, but I would describe a university or an organization as "diverse" in this sense, not the programmes or courses it may offer to its members.